# Generate negated values in Prolog

Tags: prolog, negation

Here is what I am trying to accomplish

```
fact(f1p1, f1p2).
fact(f2p1, f2p2).
fact(f3p1, f3p2).

factIsNotTrue(Param1, Param2) :-
    \+fact(Param1, Param2).
```

I want the code above to produce the following

```
?- fact_is_not_true(f1p1, Param2).
Param2 = f2p2.
Param2 = f3p2.
```

Instead I get

```
?- fact_is_not_true(f1p1, Param2).
false.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
factIsNotTrue(Param1, Param2) :-
    dif(Param1, F),
    fact(F, Param2),
    \+ fact(Param1, Param2).
```

Here we say that `Param2` is true for `fact(F, Param2)` and false for `fact(Param1, Param2)`, and that `Param1` is different from `F` using `dif/2`.

#### Sidenote

You may want to give clearer names to your variables in your code: `Param1` and `Param2` are probably not the most descriptive names.

We also recommend to name predicates using `this_formatting_convention` rather than `thisFormattingConvention`. It tends to make things more readable.

Comment: Yes, I understand that `Param1` and `Param2` are poor names. I don't use names like these in real programs. I just didn't want to distract you with my application details.

Comment: Negation and dif/2 together. Is this really safe?

Answer (score 2):

```
factIsNotTrue(Param1, Param2) :-
    \+fact(Param1, Param2).
```

The snippet above means "factIsNotTrue relation holds between `Param1` and `Param2` if `fact(Param1, Param2)` is not **provable**.

When you query `factIsNotTrue(f1p1, Param2).` Obviosuly prolog finds that `fact(f1p1, f1p2)` is in fact provable so the query fails.

You can modify your code as follows to generate the negated values:

```
param(f1p1).
param(f1p2).
param(f2p1).
param(f2p2).
param(f3p1).
param(f3p2).

fact(f1p1, f1p2).
fact(f2p1, f2p2).
fact(f3p1, f3p2).

factIsNotTrue(Param1, Param2):-
    param(Param1),
    param(Param2),
    \+ fact(Param1, Param2).
```

**Test run**:

```
?- factIsNotTrue(f1p1, Param2).
Param2 = f1p1 ;
Param2 = f2p1 ;
Param2 = f2p2 ;
Param2 = f3p1 ;
Param2 = f3p2.

?- factIsNotTrue(f1p1, f1p2).
false.
```

Comment: That's a good answer, it can get me going, but I need output in this case to be only `Param2 = f2p2; Param2 = f3p2`